# "\/" text shows up within my JSON link values

Tags: php, mysql, json, bluehost

My database contains links to images which are displayed properly within their structure. When I run my PHP code, the outputted JSON values are the same image links which fail to load because the links keep being outputted like this:

```
https:\/\/i.ebayimg.com\/00\/s\/NDQwWDgwMA==\/z\/ViAAAOSwhmtbN7fe\/$_59.JPG\r\n
```

Even though the database displays it like this:

```
https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NDQwWDgwMA==/z/ViAAAOSwhmtbN7fe/$_59.JPG
```

Is there something wrong with my PHP code?

Comment: In PHP `\\` is "escape". Meaning don't read `\\` as a special character, just read it as a string `\\` with no actions attached. Edit: see it's even impossible to write it here on SO. That's how special that character is

Comment: i see no json here ... how about showing some code no ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use string replace function in php for remove (\)

```
$your_string = str_replace("\\", "", $your_string);
```

Comment: That may work but is not the correct method to do it. What if there is a Windows path in the string?

Comment: Please send an example

Comment: It's a Json string. It can have multiple values in the same string. Just create one on your own one item with a weblink and one item with a Windows path

Comment: ? I think you are getting this path file://c:/

Answer (score 0):

Simple use [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

First remove `\r\n` using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) from link/url and then apply `stripslashes()`

```
$link = 'https:\/\/i.ebayimg.com\/00\/s\/NDQwWDgwMA==\/z\/ViAAAOSwhmtbN7fe\/$_59.JPG\r\n';
$link = stripslashes( str_replace("\\r\\n", '', $link) );
echo $link;
```

Comment: Doesn't work https://3v4l.org/1G1Qr

Comment: @Andreas i have updated my answer. https://3v4l.org/DW1Au